# Saving a variable and overwriting it - difficulties

Tags: while-loop

I have a problem. I would try to intialize max to 0, but the thing is that the integer could be negative.

I'm trying to make a program of the form (not exact):

```
public ... main() {
max=0
x=5
while(x>=0){
(prompt user for int)
(save it)
sum = x + sum;
if (x>max)
max=x;

x++;
(print max and sum)
}
}
```

This is the question:

Write a program that reads 5 integers from a file, computes their sum and maximum and prints these values to the screen. Do this by modifying the summing program from the chapter. Insert a new int variable called max which you should initialize to the first value in the file. This will call for an extra set of input statements before the loop starts. To compute the maximum you will need an if statement nested inside the loop.

Thanks alot everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer the problem yourself in the question :)

Don't give `max` any hard-coded initial value.  Always set it to the first integer in the file, and then compare every time after that.

Comment: But I'm using a loop and wouldn't it overwrite the max to the next variable? Thanks

Comment: On the first time through, you assign max to whatever is read in.  Every time after that, you compare with an if-statement to see if you should overwrite.